# Login in laravel based on role and status of a user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, laravel-4

I'm using laravel `Auth()` method for login a user. How can I redirect a particular user to admin/dashbord page, if he has 'role=1' and rediect a user to user/home page if he has 'role=2'?

And how can I prevent an user login, if his status is blocked (`status=0`)?

My user table structure is showing below. Role and status are two columns in my table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this lesson on Laracasts, [Users and Roles](https://laracasts.com/lessons/users-and-roles), which has this [source code](https://github.com/laracasts/Users-and-Roles-in-Laravel).

If you don't want to roll your own, you might want to look into [Entrust](https://github.com/zizaco/entrust).

If you'd like more of a coded answer, please include code to reference.